# How to build WinPcap from source using VS2013

Tags: winpcap, netmon

I downloaded the WinPcap sources 4.1.3 as well as the corresponding AirPcap developer kit. I followed the build instructions described from the WinPcap website [1](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__compilation.html):

I loaded the project contained in the directory PacketNTx\dll\project with VS2013 (running on Windows 7 Professional x64). When I try to build the default project configuration (Debug, Win32) I get the error that the include file "netmon.h" cannot be opened. I also searched the web and found that this file is part of the wiretap library included in the Wireshark source code...

Can anyone suggest how to build the default configuration of the WinPcap packet.dll and wpcap.dll?

Thanks in advance!
best regards!